# How to add input files in sbt Scala

Tags: scala, sbt

I am new to scala. I am using sbt assembly to create a fat jar. My program reads input files. I kept my files under src/main/resources folder.But I am getting java.io.FileNotFoundException

I dont know how to specify the path? I will delpoying the jar on the server.

Here is my sbt build file

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.insnapinc",
  version := "0.1.0",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "memcache-client"

  )
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq (

  "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "1.1.4"
  ,"org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.2.10"
  ,"org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test"

)



/* assembly plugin */
mainClass in AssemblyKeys.assembly := Some("com.insnap.memcache.MemcacheTest")

assemblySettings

test in AssemblyKeys.assembly := {}
```

Comment: Showing your sbt configuration is the least you should do...

Comment: You mean the buid file?I added it